# Integrating $z^5\sqrt{z^4-1}$ around a circle of radius 2 in $\Bbb{C}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the complex function

$$
f(z)=z^5\sqrt{z^4-1}
$$

This function clearly has branch points at $z=1,e^{i\pi/2},-1,$ and $e^{3\pi i/2}$ (the fourth roots of unity).  If we arrange our branch cuts so they all face towards the origin, we obtain a function which is analytic except for the "plus sign" $[-1,1]\cup[-i,i]$.  Now, how would I go about integrating around the circle of radius 2 centered at the origin?  The function is not analytic inside, so we can't assume the integral to be zero.  Any hints?  Am I thinking too hard about this?

Comment: Shouldn't you first define exactly what $z\mapsto \sqrt{z^4-1}$ is?

Comment: @GitGud Not sure what you mean - I've declared my branch cuts, do I need to do anything else?

Comment: You have to go around the branch points , this way you have an analytic function .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is easier to expand the contour to infinity instead of shrinking it. There is no branch point at infinity, and the function can be defined by
$$f(z)=z^5\sqrt{z^4-1}=z^7\sqrt{1-z^{-4}}$$
where the 2nd square root is defined by the principal branch. Now expanding
$$f(z)=z^7\left[1-\frac{z^{-4}}{2}-\frac{z^{-8}}{8}+\ldots\right],$$
we obtain
$$\int_{|z|=2}f(z)dz=2\pi i\cdot\left(-\frac{1}{8}\right)=-\frac{\pi i}{4}.$$

Comment: So, just to make sure I have it right, we're considering the circle as going around the point at infinity on the Riemann sphere, and thus the integral is $2\pi i\cdot$(Residue at $\infty$).  Correct?

Comment: @icurays1 Yes. Or, if you don't feel very confident with that, first make the change of variables $z\mapsto 1/z$. Then we will have to calculate the usual residue at zero. (The "plus" formed by the branch cuts will transform into four rays outside the contour).

Comment: Okay great!  Thanks.  Any idea why Mathematica is giving me a residue of $5/128$ instead of $-5/128$?  (I believe the expansion more than Mathematica, frankly...)

Comment: @icurays1 Because of the change of orientation of the contour. However, I've just noticed a misprint in my calculations - I will correct this shortly.

Comment: AH, yes.  Thanks.  Looks good now (I thought something was fishy...).

Comment: The best way to understand what is going on in my opinion is to draw the circle $|z|=2$ inside of the circle $|z|=R$, and connect the two circles with two lines that are arbitrarily close together. Then going around the contour counterclockwsie, $ \displaystyle\int_{|z|=2} f(z) dz + \lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{|z|=R} f(z) \ dz = 0$ where $ \displaystyle\lim_{R \to \infty} \int_{|z|=R} f(z) \ dz$ equals the coefficient of the $\frac{1}{z}$ term in the Laurent expansion of $f(z)$ at $\infty$.